# Temporary external mounting of 3.5" SATA/IDE drives

Tags: hardware, usb, sata, ide

What do you use for temporarily externally mounting 3.5" SATA and IDE hard drives?  When I'm in the field and just have a laptop with me, I'd like to be able to mount a client's drive to my laptop for data recovery, etc.  Is a separate USB enclosure for SATA and IDE the best option?   Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the Newer Technology USB 2.0 Universal Drive Adapter.  It's inexpensive, small, and works on IDE or SATA drives.

http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Newer%20Technology/U2NV2SPATA/

Comment: Wow, very cool.  You've had good experience with this?

Comment: Here's a review: http://www.extremeoverclocking.com/reviews/storage/Newertech_USB_Adapter_1.html

Comment: Yes I've had good experiences with it.  It's good for what it is designed for; temporary access to loose hard drives in the field.  Small and cheap.

Comment: We use a similar product and they work great.

http://www.granitedigital.com/usb20tosataideharddrivebridgeadapter.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The [ThermalTake BlacX](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/Product.aspx?S=1268&ID=1642), and other similar products, are very handy for temporarily mounting drives.  No need to grab a screwdriver to open the external case, mess with power and SATA/IDE cables, etc.  Just plug it in.

Answer (score 0):

I bought one of my clients a [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/).  It is sweet.  Almost disappointingly easy to set up.

**EDIT:**
Note, Drobo is SATA only.  No IDE...

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [WiebeTech](http://www.wiebetech.com/home.php).  They offer many options for forensic recovery.  Not the cheapest option, but they will give you a good idea of the features you might want to look for in other products.

Answer (score 0):

I swear by [IcyDock's enclosures](http://www.icydock.com/usb.html). Here's a [SATA/IDE one](http://www.icydock.com/product/mb452uk.html).

Comment: It is a pity there web site sucks...  The frames are driving me nuts!